# React with dotnet core 3.0 mvc authentication (without dotnet core default authentication)

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am building a web using ReactJS + dotnet core MVC application.
When I search I get only those samples which are using visual studios [default authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)(example: JWT methods).

I would like to use custom authentication with the controller and mysql db.

**below is my react component:**

```
import React from 'react';
export class LoginMN extends React.Component {
static displayName = LoginMN.name;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { loading: true, fields: {}, errors: {} };

}

handleValidation() {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    let errors = {};
    let isFormValid = true;

    /***************** Email validation *****************/
    if (!fields["email"]) {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors["email"] = "Email is required";
    }
    else if (typeof fields["email"] !== "undefined") {
        let lastAtPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('@');
        let lastDotPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('.');

        if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
            isFormValid = false;
            errors["email"] = "Enter a valid email id";
        }
    }
    /***************************************************/

    /*************** Password validation ***************/
    if (!fields["password"]) {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors["password"] = "Password is required";
    }
    else if (typeof fields["password"] !== "undefined") {
        let pwd = fields["password"];
        if (pwd.length < 8) {
            isFormValid = false;
            errors["password"] = "Enter valid password";
        }
    }
    /***************************************************/

    /************* Mobile number validation ************/
    if (!fields["phone"]) {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors["phone"] = "Phone number is required";
    }
    else if (typeof fields["phone"] !== "undefined") {
        let phone = fields["phone"];
        if (isNaN(phone)) {
            isFormValid = false;
            errors["phone"] = "Enter valid phone number";
        }
        else if(phone.length < 10) {
            isFormValid = false;
            errors["phone"] = "Phone number should be 10 digits";
        }
    }
    /***************************************************/

    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return isFormValid;
}

handleChange(field, e) {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getAuthenticationStatus();
}  


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Login </h2>
            <form name="contactform" className="shadow contactform" onSubmit={this.generateOtp.bind(this)}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text ">
                                    <i className="fas fa-at text-success"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    ref="email"
                                    className="form-control border-0"
                                    placeholder="Email ID*"
                                    id="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "email")}
                                    value={this.state.fields["email"]}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                {this.state.errors["email"]}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">
                                    <i className="fa fa-user-secret text-success"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input 
                                    type="password" 
                                    ref="password"
                                    className="form-control border-0" 
                                    name="password" 
                                    id="password"
                                    placeholder="Password*" 
                                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "password")}
                                    value={this.state.fields["password"]}/>
                            </div>
                            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                {this.state.errors["password"]}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">
                                    <i className="fa fa-volume-control-phone text-success"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    ref="phone" 
                                    className="form-control border-0" 
                                    name="phone" 
                                    id="phone"
                                    placeholder="10 digit phone number*" 
                                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "phone")}
                                    value={this.state.fields["phone"]}/>
                            </div>
                            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                {this.state.errors["phone"]}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <button className="btn btn-success">Generate OTP</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <hr />
            <form className="shadow hidden">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">
                                    <i className="fas fa-key text-success"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control border-0" name="otp" id="otp"
                                    placeholder="One time password(OTP) sent to your phone / email*" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="input-group shadow bg-white rounded p-3">
                                <button className="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

generateOtp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.handleValidation()) {
        //Check DB           
        console.log("isAuthenticated=" +  this.getAuthenticationStatus());
        //call SendOTP method
    }
}


async getAuthenticationStatus() {
    //IsAuthenticated method is available in Controller
    const response = await fetch('IsAuthenticated');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ loading: false });        
}

}
```

**Here is my controller class**

```
namespace sampleReactMVC.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public bool IsAuthenticated(string email, string password, string phone)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;
            UserProfile usrProfile = new UserProfile(email, password, phone);
            DBConnect myDbConnection = new DBConnect();

            //This method checks from mysql db
            isAuthenticated = UsersDbAccess.GetAuthenticationStatus(usrProfile, myDbConnection.GetConnection());

            usrProfile.SetAuthenticationStatus(isAuthenticated);
            return isAuthenticated;

        }
    }
}
```

**The Questions:**

1. How to pass data from ReactComponent to Controller through URL (/login/username/)
2. How to pass data from ReactComponent to Controller securely (for authentication, if it is through URL it will be visible)
3. Ways of passing data from ReactComponent to Controller and Vice-versa

I understand C# but react and API/WebAPI are new to me.

Please help with this needful info.